# flexbox: не работает в IE

Tags: html, flexbox

Добрый день. Имеется CSS

```
table {
display: flex;
display: -ms-flex;
flex-flow: column;
-ms-flex-flow: column;
height: 97%;
width: 100%;    
}

table thead {
flex: 0 0 auto;
-ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
width: calc(100% - 0.9em);
}

table tbody {
flex: 1 1 auto;
-ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
display: block;
overflow-y: scroll;
}



table thead, table tbody tr {
display: table;
table-layout: fixed;
width:100%;
height:20%;
}
```

применён в таблице, с целью повесить скроллинг на tbody, если tbody выходит за границы окна по вертикали (thead остаётся на месте). что-то вроде следующего:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="flextbody.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<table>
<thead><tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th><th>5</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>1 cell 1</td><td>cell 2</td><td>cell 3</td><td>cell 4</td><td>cell 5</td></tr>
```

здесь повторить последний тэг tr, ну скажем, 30 раз, чтобы вышло за границы экрана по вертикали, и закрываем

```
</tbody></table></body></html>
```

проблема в том, что скроллинг tbody прекрасно появляется в Chrome и Firefox, но вот IE (11) игнорирует флекс. Как исправить, чтобы работало в IE?

Comment: а доктайп прописан?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Флекс только для современных браузеров! 
Как решить? - Не использовать flex!

Comment: ну вот как раз написано для IE11 - "partial support"

Comment: да, вот доктайп как раз не прописал

Comment: не понимаю. дописал <!DOCTYPE html> (HTML5), скроллинг tbody перестал работать и в Firefox с Хромом.